# "Tags" blade during Azure Notificaiton Hubs setup

Tags: azure, configuration, notification

I'm setting up a new Notification Hub and I've come across a new tab/blade that I'm unsure what to do with. I don't recall seeing this blade in the past.

I understand the notion of "tags" as a means of categorizing your notification recipient groups. Using this, I should be able to dispatch to select "tags" or groups.

But I don't know what the "value" box is **for** here.

[image]

I've gone through multiple documents ([a](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message#feedback), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43347199/1664443), [c](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification)) on setting up Azure Notification Hubs but I don't see this part of the configuration explained anywhere.

When clicking the information icon above "Name" or above "Value", this is what's displayed. (Both are nearly identical)

[image]

This tells me what a "valid" entry is, but doesn't offer any clues into how these values will be actually used.

## Question

What is an example of a "Name" and a "Value" for the "Tags" tab? Could you please briefly describe how they are used?

Comment: What does the information icon next to each of them say? Does it give you any useful information?

Comment: I've updated the post with a screenshot of what the "I" icon shows. This information merely tells me what I **can** put in there, but not what I **should** put in there. For example, entering gibberish into each is technically valid, but not necessarily useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is the normal Azure resource tag configuration to me. It's purely for your own use, as you see fit - for example, you may choose to store a Tag as Cost Center or Business Unit. It doesn't impact the usage or function of the resource itself.

Once you've created a Tag once, I think it will then be automatically selectable for new Azure resources.

You can then use tags as a filter when running powershell scripts or running reports etc.

Or, you can simple leave it blank

Comment: So let’s say I want to use this tagging system to notify “admin” users and not “member” users. I would set the `Name` as “admin”, but what is the purpose of the `value` input? I feel like I’m being dense here, sorry ha

Comment: You don't, because these Tags aren't related to the operation of the resource (i.e. the Notification Hub). They're meta data, if you like, on the resource itself. You can also add them to VMs, storage etc. They're name value pairs because you literally make them up and use them how you see fit. For example, you may choose to link resources to their project. So you'd literally make up a project tag, and fill in "My project". But it doesn't do anything, except give you a way to filter and search later

Comment: Ahha, thanks for clearing this up Dan